# Exiting with 1 in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, return, cs50

This is one of my first programs in Python, so I might be missing something obvious.

In this first part of my code that I've posted, I'd like to make sure the user passes a command line argument. If not, I want to show an error and return 1. When I run the code without a command line argument, the program has the expected behavior because the error prints and the program exits.

However, when I run a checker on this, I get an error:

> handles lack of argv[1]. expected exit code 1, not 0.

Any ideas on what I may be missing?

```
import sys
import cs50
from cs50 import get_string


def main(argv):
    # Check for command line argument
    if (len(sys.argv) != 2):
        print("Error: Please input numeric key in command line.")
        return 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: `sys.exit(1)` is what you need.

Comment: Yes! That did it!  Thank you!

Comment: @kwicz Just fyi, the parentheses enclosing your if-statement condition are redundant. Python does not require them.

Answer (score 7):

In a [blog post](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=4829), Guido van Rossum, the creator of Python, suggests writing the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

This way, `main()` can return a value, like a normal function, and it will be used as an exit code for the process.

I suggest reading the rest of that blog post. It contains helpful suggestions for setting up Python `main()` function boilerplate to be more flexible.

Comment: Did you mean to include a link to the blog post?

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for catching that. Done!